# Textured triangles with OpenGL using VBO/IBO

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw out two textured triangles to make a square using a VBO containing the coordinates on the screen and coordinates of the texture and an IBO with the indices. However I'm running into a problem. Without using a shader I get the correct size and position of the two triangles but no texture no matter how I try. With a shader I get a texture but the triangle is wrong size, in the wrong position and not using the texture coordinates in any way.

**Creating the texture**

```
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nOfColors, surface->w, surface->h, 0,
                        texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);
```

**Filling the VBO and IBO**
(TileData is a struct with two size 2 arrays)

```
    indices.push_back(0);
    indices.push_back(1);
    indices.push_back(2);
    indices.push_back(0);
    indices.push_back(2);
    indices.push_back(3);

    TileData tile;

    tile.texCoord[0] = 0 / imageSizeX;
    tile.texCoord[1] = 0 / imageSizeY;
    tile.worldCoord[0] = 0;
    tile.worldCoord[1] = 0;
    tiles.push_back(tile);

    tile.texCoord[0] = (0 + texWidth) / imageSizeX;
    tile.texCoord[1] = 0 / imageSizeY;
    tile.worldCoord[0] = 0 + texWidth;
    tile.worldCoord[1] = 0;
    tiles.push_back(tile);

    tile.texCoord[0] = (0 + texWidth) / imageSizeX;
    tile.texCoord[1] = (0 + texHeight) / imageSizeY;
    tile.worldCoord[0] = 0 + texWidth;
    tile.worldCoord[1] = 0 + texHeight;
    tiles.push_back(tile);

    tile.texCoord[0] = 0 / imageSizeX;
    tile.texCoord[1] = (0 + texHeight) / imageSizeY;
    tile.worldCoord[0] = 0;
    tile.worldCoord[1] = 0 + texHeight;
    tiles.push_back(tile);
```

This gives code gives me the world coordinates and texture coordinates:

```
0, 0          0, 0
16, 0         0.25, 0
16, 16        0.25, 1
0, 16         0, 1
```

**Generate my buffers**

```
        glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tiles.size() * sizeof(TileData), &tiles[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &iboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID); 
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

**Draw function with shader**

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(camera.x, camera.x + 320, camera.y + 240, camera.y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shaderHandler.programID);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    GLint texLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderHandler.programID, "tex");

    glUniform1i(texLocation, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CGame::TileData), (GLvoid *)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CGame::TileData), (GLvoid*)offsetof(CGame::TileData, CGame::TileData::worldCoord));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID); 
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices->size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

**Result**
[With shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7mzM.png)

**Draw function without shader**
(The above code can also get the same result as this one if I unlink the shaderprogram)

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(CGame::TileData), (GLvoid*)0);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(CGame::TileData), (GLvoid*)offsetof(CGame::TileData, CGame::TileData::worldCoord));

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID); 
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices->size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)0);

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); 
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

**Resulst** 
[Without shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KysCr.png)

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec2 vert;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertTexCoord;

out vec2 fragTexCoord;

void main() 
{
    fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord; 
    gl_Position = vec4(vert, 0, 1);
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D tex; 
in vec2 fragTexCoord; 
out vec4 finalColor; 

void main() 
{
    finalColor = texture2D(tex, fragTexCoord);
}
```

At this point I've no idea how to continue. I can't find anything that helps me on here or anywhere. I've tried so much things that I probably use something deprecated or doing something unsupported but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues:

1. In the fixed function, you have to explicitely call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` to tell the GL that your currently bound 2D texture shall be applied (separately for each texture unit).
2. Your vertex shader does never transform the vertices according to your transform state. All the matrix-related GL functions like `glOrtho`, `glTranslate`, `glMatrixMode` are deprecated. You have to use your own matrix functions (or a library like glm) and supply the matrices to the shader via uniforms (or other means). In a compatiblity profile, you could also use the GLSL builtin uniforms which allow you to access the old builtin matrices set with those deprecated functions, but I strongly recommend to not rely on deprecated functionality. In either case, your shader has to actually apply your vertex and modelview transformations, which typically boils down to matrix-vector products like `projection * modelView * vec4(pos,1)`.
3. Your attribute pointers are weird, to say the least. You use an offset of 0 for the vertex positions, and and offset of `offsetof(...::worldCoord)` for the *texture* coordinates. Now depending on which order your members are defined, both might point to the exact same values in memory, which would explain the "and not using the texture coordinates in any way" part you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have used glEnable just missed it when pasting code. I did try making a modelview/projection matrix before but I seem to have done it wrong or maybe forgot to remove the glMatrix-functions before testing I don't remember. And yes, they were wierd, for some reason I thought of them as sort of a stride argument or something, that ::worldCoord would make it skip that part. But I fixed that so now it uses the correct part of the texture! Just projection left.